# SharePoint Workflow Update List Item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

It is possible to define in Sharepoint Workflow, in Update List Item function, which column in specified list have to be updated by variable?

[image]

Comment: Erm, the answer regarding your question is shown in your screenshot. There you define which field in which list should be updated with which value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but screenshot only show what I try to do, unfortunately in "Value Assignment" window, in "Set this field" I can choose only specific column from "Another List", I would like to put there a "Variable", which will be defined by workflow or other similar way.. And this Variable should decide which column will be updated in Another list in specific "case", because in "case 1" I need to update column "A", in "case 2" i need to update column "B"... up to 48 cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to create 48 if statements. Allthough it is possible to create loops in sharepoint designer it wouln't solve your problem, because a loop excecutes something as many times as you want or until a specific condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of IF statements within the workflow to compare the variable to a known value.

```
IF variable isequal value1
  set field X in list y
```

In this case you would need to list all 48 potential values in separate IF statement blocks. 
It's cumbersome, but in the absence of loops (which aren't available in workflows) it works :)